# Get the visibility status of a toolbar according to Customize perspective dialog in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm working on a plug-in, which contributes to the toolbar. The toolbar is listed in the Customize perstpective dialog. When I uncheck the check-box, the toolbar disappears as expected. But when the toolbar is updated from my code (using the toolbar manager), it gets displayed again. I need to get somehow the visibility status from code in order to prevent the toolbar from beeing updated when disabled.

Do you anybody have any idea, where the Customize perspective dialog stores the visibility status of menus and toolbars and how to get it from code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get information by item ID this way:

```
private static boolean isToolbarItemVisible(String id){
    IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
    IWorkbenchWindow workbenchWindow = workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

    return !((WorkbenchPage) workbenchWindow.getActivePage()).getHiddenItems().contains((ModeledPageLayout.HIDDEN_TOOLBAR_PREFIX + id + ","));
}
```